# Changing the font style changes UI - standard approach

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, styling

I built an HTML navigation strip using ul and li tags.

```
<div id="navLimitedLength">
    <ul id="navmenulist">
        <li class="menu"><a>Add</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a>Update</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a>View</a></li>
        <li class="menu"><a>Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Intially I set it to have Arial font using CSS as follows:

```
    li.menu a
    {   
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:18px;         
    }
```

Then I tried to change the font to Segoe UI as follows:

```
li.menu a
{   
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size:18px;         
}
```

However this also changes the look of menus making them to overlap down
[image]

As far as I understand, changing font should not change other styling. This may be since I am trying it in IE8.

**But what is the standard way to ensure that things remain in place and behave in desired way.**

Comment: Different fonts have different sizes between letters, on top and below letters as well. This is to be expected when changing fonts, they're not uniform and all the same. You either should change the font-size or line-height or experiment with paddings and margins between the `li`s.

Comment: but then its like whenever am changing font I have to feedle other style properties too, isnt that feels somewhat un-standard

Comment: Try fixed height (at least with `em`/`ex` unit) on your `<li>`/`<a>` and padding/margin/line-height.

Comment: The issue cannot be seen when testing with the code posted. You should include minimal code that actually demonstrates the problem. Presumably, you have set some background colors, dimensions, and `display` property settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is caused by different default line heights for different fonts. By CSS specifications, the initial value of [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) is `normal`, and by the spec, browsers are *expected* to “to set the used value to a ‘reasonable’ value based on the font of the element”. If you inspect the situation in Firebug, you can see that for 18px Arial, the used value is 22px, but for Segoe UI it is 25px.

In this case, adding e.g. `line-height: 1.2` into the style sheet would help.

Answer (score 0):

Different fonts have different standards. So I would suggest you to decrease the line height. It will solve your problem.

Adjust the line-height using firebug in firefox to get the exact line -height

```
li.menu a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:10px; //this value is for sample purpose
}
```